# $ \text{rank}(Z^t Z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to prove that $\text{rank}(Z^T Z)=p$, when $Z$ is an $n\times p$-matrix which has rank $p$. By assumption, $Z$ has $p$ linearly independent columns, let's call them $z_1,...,z_p$. Then

$Z^TZ=\begin{pmatrix} z_1^T & \\ \vdots \\ z_p^T \end{pmatrix}(z_1,...,z_p)=\begin{pmatrix} z_1^T z_1 & \dots & z_1^Tz_p \\ \vdots &  & \vdots \\ z_p^Tz_1 &\dots &z_p^T z_p\end{pmatrix}$

by rules of block matrices. Now, denote by $\tilde z_1,...,\tilde z_p$ the columns of $Z^TZ$. We have to prove

$\alpha_1\tilde z_1+...+\alpha_p \tilde z_p=0 \Rightarrow \alpha_1=...=\alpha_p=0$.

The left hand side is equivalent to demanding

$\alpha_1 z_i^Tz_1+...+\alpha_p z_i^Tz_p=0 \ \forall i$. Writing this in the more convenient form with the standard scalar product, we get

$\alpha_1 <z_i,z_1>+...+\alpha_p <z_i,z_p>=0 \ \forall i$ and by bilinearity

$<z_i, \alpha_1z_1+...+\alpha_pz_p>=0 \ \forall i$, which implies $\alpha_1z_1+...+\alpha_pz_p=0$. By assumption, $\alpha_1=...=\alpha_p=0$ and we are done. Is this proof correct? And exist proofs, that don't require such calculations?

Comment: Yes, there are quicker proofs. For example, it helps to notice that $x^T(Z^TZ)x= \|Zx\|^2$. Using this fact, we can see that $Z$ and $Z^TZ$ have the same null space.

Comment: So it goes like this: If x is such that $Zx=0$, then obviously $Z^TZx=0$. On the other hand, if $Z^TZx=0$, then, by the above equation, $Zx=0$. Therefore, $Z$ and $Z^TZ$ have the same null space, namely $\{0\}$. By the rank-nullity equality, we must then have $\text{rank}(Z^TZ)=p$.

Comment: Precisely. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$